# softlayer API missing serverRoom

Tags: python, ruby, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm seeing an issue where the SoftLayer API is missing the `serverRoom` field for over 75% of our servers. I've confirmed this using both their python and ruby libraries (https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/managers/hardware/#SoftLayer.managers.hardware.HardwareManager.list_hardware and https://softlayer.github.io/ruby/server_locate/ respectively). Note that the ruby code I'm running is simply one of their published examples.

It seems like SoftLayer has a naming convention of creating FQDN like `[dataCenter].[serverRoom].[rackNumber].[slotNumber]`. I'm not sure if it is just another indicator of the problem or helpful in troubleshooting the root cause, but the servers that are missing `serverRoom` seem to be named incorrectly by SoftLayer, according to what appears to be SoftLayer's naming convention. They are named `[dataCenter].[rackNumber].[slotNumber]`, notably missing `serverRoom`.

Basically it looks like their database (which I assume is backing their API) is just missing the `serverRoom` for most of the hosts, or they named most of our hosts incorrectly and the database can't account for it, so the info is missing when I call their API. Does anyone have a similar experience where SoftLayer perhaps named things wrong, or forgot to do this data entry, or are there some other/different API calls I should be making beyond what SoftLayer themselves recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoftLayer support confirmed that there was a some sort of block on hidden sites where this info wasn't displayed via their API. Thanks to @ruber-cuellar was who said something similar in one of his comments, but I disagree that "There is not an issue." From my perspective there definitely was an issue that they (SoftLayer support) needed to resolve on their end before their example API calls started showing us all the info. Special thanks to ALLmightySPIFF on #softlayer who was able to repro the issue for me and provided a realtime response.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to verify and reproduce the issue that you mentioned, but I couldn't. please Submit a ticket with all the information that you can provide to verify and isolate this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I've got a ticket in, and support told me to post to SO because that's how we should resolve "API issues" (when I use the example code they gave me, no less!). And you're pointing me back to submitting a ticket - do you mean in the SL ticketing system or in one of the softlayer-ruby or softlayer-python github repos? 27653525

Comment: SL ticketing system, let me take a look

Comment: There is not an issue, apparently there is a flag which avoids to show server Room info, as soon as possible you will have an answer in the ticket about this situation.